# Does SharePoint 2010 Online offer document level encryption?

Tags: sharepoint, encryption, sharepoint-2010, document

I know there are several products that encrypt at the document level when self or privately hosted, but is there a way to encrypt at the document level when using Microsoft's cloud hosted/online solution?

Comment: This belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways

1) Write a custom workflow which has your custom logic to encrypt and decrypt files.

2) If you are using the object model you can easily encrypt the file just before calling update.

I would try this personally and cover it in my next blog if possible.

Let me know.